# Can a trigger prevent an insert/update without cancelling other inserts/updates?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, database-trigger

I want a trigger that can ignore a subset of inserts/updates without affecting the others. For example, if out of 10 inserts/updates we have 2 that are invalid, I want to skip those 2 and carry out the other 8.

So far the only way to not insert/update I have found that works is to raise an error, but from what I can tell this prevents the other inserts and updates from happening.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You should show the trigger.  Explain what the errors are.  Are you doing 10 inserts on a single trigger?  Or is that 10 calls to the trigger?

Comment: Please paste your trigger so we have more context and can provide a detailed response. Many ways to do this, I would use `INSTEAD OF` trigger, not after or for... then you can insert/update a filtered set of rows or columns depending on your conditions